# MySQL How to GROUP BY counted column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

I have two tables users, orders

each table has below column

```
users(table)
id

orders(table)
user_id
```

How can i get the number of users whose order count is 1,2,3,4 ....n?

Like this?

```
users count    |   order count
999            |   1
100            |   2
 80            |   3
 70            |   4
 60            |   5
 50            |   6
```

What I have been trying so far is

```
SELECT cnt.uid as u_cnt, cnt.ocnt as or_cnt
FROM (
  SELECT u.id as uid, COUNT(o.id) as o_cnt
  FROM users as u
  INNER JOIN orders o on u.id = o.user_id
) as cnt;
GROUP BY or_cnt
```

BUT I get only 1 u_cnt and summed or_cnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two levels of `group by` clauses here: First, you need to group by user and count the number of orders each user has. Then, you need to take that result, group by the number of orders and count how many users have such an order count.

The easiest way to achieve this is probably with a subquery, where both the inner and outer query have a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT cnt.ocnt as or_cnt, COUNT(*) as user_count
FROM (
  SELECT u.id as uid, COUNT(o.id) as o_cnt
  FROM users as u
  INNER JOIN orders o on u.id = o.user_id
  GROUP BY u.id -- This was missing in your original query
) as cnt
GROUP BY or_cnt
```

Comment: There is no `kid` alias defined in the subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh It was uid in the subquery

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen copies the OP's query and got carried away. It's missing another `count` call - edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation.  More importantly, you do not need a `JOIN`.  All the information you need is in `orders`:

```
SELECT o_cnt, COUNT(*) as user_count
FROM (SELECT o.user_id, COUNT(*) as o_cnt
      FROM orders o
      GROUP BY o.user_id 
     ) u
GROUP BY o_cnt
ORDER BY o_cnt;
```